# How to handle the *args in Python when no arguments are passed over to the Function parameter

Tags: python, function, arguments

Let's say I have a function given below:

```
def splitter(*params):
    rep, msg = params
    if rep:
        for i in range(rep):
            print(i)
    else:
       print('-----------------------------------')


splitter(2,'Let the Game Begin!! ')
```

Now, in the above case it will pass since I'm giving the arguments, but what I want is, that suppose I don't want to give the arguments when calling the function, then how can I handle it? Since ****args*** cannot have a default value.

Comment: Only do `rep, msg = params` if `params` has more than 1 value.

Comment: You could do something like this: `rep, msg = params or (None, None)`

Comment: This function only works if it receives exactly two arguments. Why does it takes `*params` in the first place? Why isn't it `def splitter(rep, msg)`?

Comment: because in some cases, I don't want to pass any argument to it, like this: ```def splitter()```

Comment: First, `*args` is for when it makes sense to call a function with any number of arguments. That's not the case here. Second, assuming you want to hit the `else` case with that call, it seems to make more sense for that functionality to be a separate function.

Answer (score 0):

Define the function with named arguments having default values:

```
def splitter(rep=None, msg=None):
    if rep is not None:
        ...
```